# Rails dynamic form submitting. Incorrect format of json in request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I try to create and send dynamic form in coffeescript and submit json data to the server:

```
    upload_form = $('<form>', {
      'action': '/save_orders',
      'method': 'post'
      'encrypt': 'application/json'
    }).append($('<input>', {
      'type': 'json'
      'name': 'data'
      'value': orders_as_json
    })).append($('<input>', {
      'type': 'hidden',
      'name': 'authenticity_token',
      'value': window._token
    }));
    upload_form.submit();
```

But when it comes on the server 'data' parameter looks invalid: `{"data"=>"`[{`\"date\":\"9/15/2014\",\"name\":\"James\"}]` and `request.headers["Content-Type"]` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

So, how can i fix it and pass real json data to the server from my dynamic form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is like:

```
1.9.3-p374 :043 > data
=> "[{\"date\":\"9/15/2014\",\"name\":\"James\"}]" 
1.9.3-p374 :042 > JSON.parse data
=> [{"date"=>"9/15/2014", "name"=>"James"}]
```

Will that help?

Comment: Yeah thx!! And how can I verify strong Params for parsed data?

Comment: Can you give me an eg? will like array of param?